# Units in ring of integers of $5^{th}$ cyclotomic field

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$ with $\omega$ a primitive $5^{\text{th}}$ root of unity. I'm trying to prove that
$$ \mathcal{O}_K^\times=\left\{\pm\omega^{a}\left(\frac{1}2+\frac{\sqrt{5}}2\right)^b: a,b\in \mathbb{Z}\right\}.$$
I've proven that $\sqrt{5}\in K$ by finding the discriminant. Since $r+s-1=1$ we also have that by Dirichlet's unit theorem
$$ \mathcal{O}_K^\times\cong \mu_K\times \mathbb{Z}.$$

Since $r+s-1=1$ there will be a fundamental unit and if $\frac{1}2+\frac{\sqrt{5}}2$ is a fundamental unit then we will be done - but this is where I am stuck. I know how to find fundamental units in quadratic number fields but I don't see how I'd extend that method to here.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: $K$ is a quadratic extension of ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{5})$. If the unit of the quadratic subextension is not fundamental, it must become a square up to a root of unity. This is impossible in your case for a variety of reasons (Galois group, . . . )

Comment: Could you explain why if a unit of the quadratic subextension is not fundamental it must be a square up to a root of unity. I also don't see why such a thing would be impossible with respect to the galois group?

Comment: If $\eta$ is not fundamental, then $\eta = \zeta^k \cdot \varepsilon^n$. If $k = 0$, then $K = k(\sqrt[n]{\eta})$, hence $n = 2$. But adjoining the square root of $\eta$ generates a nonnormal extension. Excluding the case $k \ne 0$ should not be too hard.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $$f: O_K^\times\to \Bbb{Z}[\varphi]^\times, z\to |z|^2$$
where $\varphi= \frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$.

- $\ker f = \{ a\in O_K^\times,\forall \sigma\in Hom_\Bbb{Q}(K,\Bbb{C}),|\sigma(a)|=1\} = \mu_{10}$
- $\text{Im }f\subset \Bbb{Z}[\varphi]^\times \cap \Bbb{R}_{> 0} = \varphi^\Bbb{Z}$
- $\varphi^{2\Bbb{Z}}\subset \text{Im } f$
- $\varphi\not \in \text{Im } f$ because $f(z)\equiv z^2\bmod (\zeta_5-1)$ while $\varphi \equiv \frac12 \bmod (\zeta_5-1)$ is not a square in $O_K/(\zeta_5-1)\cong \Bbb{F}_5$.
- Whence $\text{Im } f = \varphi^{2\Bbb{Z}}$ and $$O_K^\times = \ker f\times \varphi^\Bbb{Z}$$

Comment: Could you explain why $f(z)\equiv z^2\mod{(\zeta_5-1)}$ and why $\varphi\equiv \frac{1}2\mod{(\zeta_5-1)}$

Comment: Use the [quadratic Gauss sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_Gauss_sum) or direct complex number representations to render $\sqrt5=\pm(\zeta-\zeta^2-\zeta^3+\zeta^4)$, the $\pm$ sign depending on which primitive root is chosen for $\zeta$. This factors as $\pm\zeta(\zeta+1)(\zeta-1)^2$, so $\sqrt5$ is a multiple of $\zeta-1$ and $\varphi\equiv\frac12\bmod(\zeta-1)$ follows.